# Tomcat many NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller instances filling memory up

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, nio, connector

I'm having a somewhat recurrent problem with an application using Tomcat 7.0.42 over Java 7 (`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)`)

The problem is that, without any visible cause, and apparently at random (obviously it's not, I think) the Java Heap fills up to more than 75%, and a full gargbage collection gets activated.

The problem is, after the FullGC, none of the memory is released, so, the FullGC starts over again. This repeats continuosly and so, the CPU is busy only executing the GC and almost no CPU cycle is given to any other thread, effectively hanging all the other Tomcat threads.

This happens in the span of no more than 5 or 10 minutes.

It doesn't seem to be related to the system load, because this happens also when I don't have more than 2 threads active and running.

Even trying to get a Heap or Stack dump is difficult due to the unresponsivnes of the Java process.

I did, anyway, get a heap histogram one time, and, unfortunately I don't have the full histogram now (my bad, I deleted the file without notice) but I kept this information from a chat:

```
1:      48504970     1552159040  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller$2
2:      48506821     1164163704  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node
```

As you can see, there are more than 48k instances of `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector$BlockPoller$2` and a same quantity of the `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node` instances (this ones are holded by the first ones). This holds up to almost 2.5GB and my memory heap is 3GB.

I have a jstack thread dump of one of the times this issue arised, that I cant post here do to character limitations. If anyone wants to look at it, please ask and I will share it.

The only solution that I have right now is killing the Tomcat java processes and starting the server again.

What could be the reason for this?

Even the time of ocurrence seems random-ish. It ocurrs sometimes at morning, sometimes at evening. One day it ocurred two times on the same day (with a Tomcat restart in the middle).

I am running Tomcat 7.0.42 on Java 7 (build 1.7.0_51-b13) over Linux (`Linux version 3.10.0-123.9.2.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Oct 28 18:05:26 UTC 2014`).

I also have instances of JBoss Infinispan Cache, and Apollo MQ message service, but I don't think either of those is the culprit.

Comment: Please provide a thread dump of your application when the problem occurs.

Comment: @benbenw, thanks for your reponse! IHere is a link to the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_dQKrkjWdg_MU51MjBESG9fVlE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Most of your http threads are blocked in log4j.

You probably have a log4j level too low (eg trace)

This leads to :

- contention
- memory allocations
- bad performance

Due to contention, the memory is held longer.

Try to set the log4j level to WARN.

This may not correct all your problems BUT it will help.

Comment: thanks for your response!

I noticed that too, but I cannot know if the block and the contention via log4j happens after or before, because, due to the GC occupying most of the CP Utime, no threads can excecute their code, so, I think is expectable that things get locked as the threads holding the locks cannot advance and release them

The other thing is that this happens  really quickly, and then, with the same (or more) amount of HTTP load (and, thereferoe, MORE logging) this doesn't ocurr again.

I'm definitely going to tune log4j performance but I doubt that this is the real cause...